# Oracle - Any way to write this query in a single Select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM View_ExecutiveForecastReport
    WHERE WORKGROUPID IN (94)
)
PIVOT  (SUM(COURSELENGTH) AS LENGTH FOR (WORKGROUPID) IN (
94 as "B2B",
66 as "CFS",
69 as "800IB",
76 as "TSData",
99 as "RetailSales",
103 as "Telesales"
))
```

I'd like to instead write it using a single SELECT instead of nesting.  I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM View_ExecutiveForecastReport
WHERE WORKGROUPID IN (94)
PIVOT  (SUM(COURSELENGTH) AS LENGTH FOR (WORKGROUPID) IN (
94 as "B2B",
66 as "CFS",
69 as "800IB",
76 as "TSData",
99 as "RetailSales",
103 as "Telesales"
))
```

But I get the error: *ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended*

I've also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM View_ExecutiveForecastReport
PIVOT  (SUM(COURSELENGTH) AS LENGTH FOR (WORKGROUPID) IN (
94 as "B2B",
66 as "CFS",
69 as "800IB",
76 as "TSData",
99 as "RetailSales",
103 as "Telesales"
))
WHERE WORKGROUPID IN (94)
```

Which gives me the error: *ORA-00904: "WORKGROUPID": invalid identifier*

If I remove the WHERE clause, the query works fine.  I'm also open to solutions that use a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because PIVOT is part of the table_reference portion of the FROM clause [table_reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2126863), which is why this works:

```
SELECT * FROM View_ExecutiveForecastReport
PIVOT  (SUM(COURSELENGTH) AS LENGTH FOR (WORKGROUPID) IN (
94 as "B2B",
66 as "CFS",
69 as "800IB",
76 as "TSData",
99 as "RetailSales",
103 as "Telesales"
))
```

Since workgroupid is not returned as a column in the PIVOT transformation, you can't use it in the WHERE clause. The usage of SELECT * FROM (subquery) PIVOT is quite common, so I suggest you use it.

Comment: When I try this I get `ORA-00904: "WORKGROUPID": invalid identifier`

Comment: Oops, I missed that. Remember that PIVOT changes the table presented by FROM, so unless you're presenting it as part of the pivot then it won't exist in the columns returned. Just use the original version.

Comment: Ok so the official answer is there is no way to do this without using a nested query?

Comment: I don't know about official, but it appears so. I don't have an 11g instance handy to try this on right now or I'd look into it more.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, it's probably better this way. You're doing the filtering in the subselect so the pivot only has to run against the smaller set of data as opposed to doing a pivot on everything then picking out the piece you need.

Comment: Valid point, it just complicates my SQL generation code a bit so I wanted to make sure..  Everything you say makes perfect sense though.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to post a CTE version of the working query as well, though I don't know if this offers any advantages over my original working query.

```
WITH V AS (SELECT * FROM View_ExecutiveForecastReport WHERE WORKGROUPID IN (94))
    SELECT * FROM V
    PIVOT  (SUM(COURSELENGTH) AS LENGTH FOR (WORKGROUPID) IN (
    94 as "B2B",
    66 as "CFS",
    69 as "800IB",
    76 as "TSData",
    99 as "RetailSales",
    103 as "Telesales"
    ))
```

Comment: It still does a subselect, so I suspect it's the same.

Comment: Yea it's probably just syntactical preferences at this point.